# Using transition to absolute position on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to get a transitional animation on a DIV on hover. However, it's not working. I feel like I'm missing something!

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hqzshhpt/)**

HTML

```
<div class="profile__container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SGw04SV.jpg" class="profile__list--resume img-fluid" />
          <div class="profile__button">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.profile__button {
  display: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #08ca77 60%);
  padding: 120px 15px 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.profile__container:hover .profile__button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You can't transtion the `position` property.

Comment: Or the `display` property. You could used `opacity` instead but you'll probably have to tweak other things to make this approach feasible https://jsfiddle.net/s1Lke083/.

Comment: what kind of transition are you looking for ? left to right ? bottom to top ? transparent to gradient ?

Comment: Thank You @HiddenHobbes Please create an answer. I'll mark yours as correct.

Comment: @ElaineByene No worries, but I chose to give direction in a comment rather than provide a full answer so feel free to accept one of the existing ones instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `display` property use `opacity` and `visibility` as shown below.

```css
.profile__button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #08ca77 60%);
  padding: 120px 15px 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: .5s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.profile__container:hover .profile__button {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile__container">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/SGw04SV.jpg" class="profile__list--resume img-fluid" />
          <div class="profile__button">
            <h2>Hello World</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Probably because @HiddenHobbes thought I stole his answers.

Comment: Visibility is not necessary.

Comment: @Kushtrim Feel free to think that, but you'd be wrong. I would take a guess that whoever downvoted did so because you didn't explain why the changes you suggested were required.

Comment: @SilverSurfer yes it is. If this is somehow used as an overlay it will cover the whole area and prevent the user from interacting with any element shown in the page.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Sorry, that was just a wild guess because I was pissed off with why it was down voted.

Comment: No problem , it was an easy assumption to make, although if you think about it if I was that worried about points I would have lost even more by downvoting you!

Answer (score 0):

```
.profile__container {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.profile__button, div.profile__button:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 70px 15px 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

div.profile__button {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #08ca77 30%);
  opacity: 1;
}

div.profile__button:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #08ca77 90%);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```